# Function which uses .push within a forloop is continuously assigning value to the array

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a .push within a for loop and the array is returned via a function, it is returning infinitely!

When I used a simple .map then this worked as expected but i needed to add an extra field (fullName) so i switched to the for loop and the .push method, although before i even did this if i consoled this.participantImage then it would carry on returning the value to the console but it would repeatedly display the array which had the single value whereas now its just filling up the array continuously.

the function is below:

```
participantImage = []
getParticipantDetails(session) {

    for (var i = 0; i < session.roles.length; i++) {

        this.participantImage.push({ images:
            session.roles[i].account.thumbnailURL, title:
            session.roles[i].account.fullName })
    }
    return this.participantImage;
}
```

The returned value is sent to a parent component in angular where it is then used to display the images in the front-end.

the component takes the function in like below:

```
      [participantImages]="getParticipantDetails(session)"
```

this is parsed to the parent component via input:

```
  @Input() participantImages?: any[] = [];

  <div class="Session-Participants">
  <div  *ngFor="let image of participantImages" >
      <img [src]='image?.images' width=100px/> // heres where im using the images
  </div>
  </div>
```

my expected result is that the array will not repeatedly fill with the data and in the front end the images wont be never ending!

Comment: what is the value of `session.roles.length`? is it different from the length of `participantImage`?

Comment: It differs, so each session that enters the function can have different amounts of roles, but in my test case it's length is just 1, whereas participantImage is an empty array

Comment: Even without the for loop this is still happening?

Comment: It's ~~reasonably well known~~ (no it's not, I've made this mistake before myself) in angular not to bind methods in views, because the methods get called for every lifecycle event, so your method is likely being called a lot more than you think. Start there.

Comment: can't you just pass to the child component `participantImage`: `[participantImages]="participantImages"`, since you have it already calculated by parent. Update it again if sessions changes